# Who has right-of-way at this stop sign; left-turner who arrived first, or non-turner who arrived later?

Tags: usa, driving, regulations, new-york-state

The situation is a two-way stop on opposite sides of a normal road.

The driver on the south side arrives with the intent to turn left, but must wait for traffic to pass. While this first driver is waiting, another driver arrives at the north end of the intersection with the intent to go straight through. At this point, both drivers are waiting for traffic to pass. Once traffic passes, which driver has the right-of-way?

This lovely MSPaint diagram should help clarify the scenario.

[image: 1]]

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: USA - New York specifically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about traveling within the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: @choster I suppose you're right - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270184/where-to-ask-driving-questions-has-a-site-including-driving-questions-ever-been mentions as much, but it sounds like there isn't a better place to ask, and I saw some other stop sign protocol questions on this SE. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Hi Dylan, and welcome to TSE. I don't know if the SE model is a good fit for legal questions, as this is phrased. From a strictly legal angle, no one can assert a right of way—the law only tells you when you must yield it. The [NYS Driver's Manual](https://dmv.ny.gov/brochure/mv21.pdf) gives the basic rule is that traffic approaching an intersection yields to traffic already in the intersection, and left-turning traffic yields to traffic going straight or turning right from the oncoming direction.

Comment: FWIW, I would expect the left-turning car in your scenario to yield to the oncoming car if they start off at the same time. If this were a four-way stop, or if the left-turning car is quicker off the mark and can complete the turn before the oncoming car enters the intersection, it would be fine, but racing to do that probably increases the risk of an accident or road rage.

Comment: Plainly, the car who has to turn in front of another car, should give way, just as when there are no stop signs. Suppose you were both on the main highway facing east and west, and one is turning. It's a no-brainer. Even if that traffic were stationary, the turning car still does not have **right of way**.

Comment: @Dylan Being about driving laws, I'd suggest you ask on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/), which i think it's a better fit!

Comment: @gmauch thanks for the suggestion. I almost reposted this question over there but found https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8688/who-has-right-of-way-at-an-intersection-with-two-stop-signs-across-from-each-oth which is nearly identical to this question. Only difference is that the north driver in my scenario is turning right instead of straight.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, unless a jurisdiction overrides this, the person going straight has the right-of-way (or to be more precise, the person turning left must yield it).

"Sequence of arrival" doesn’t have much persistency, and the passing car breaks it.